# How to shift and stack two columns of pandas Dataframe into one column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe mentioned below:

```py
                   ETHNIC            SEX  USUBJID
0      HISPANIC OR LATINO              F       16
1      HISPANIC OR LATINO              M        8
2      HISPANIC OR LATINO  Total__##!!??       24
3  NOT HISPANIC OR LATINO              F       25
4  NOT HISPANIC OR LATINO              M       18
5  NOT HISPANIC OR LATINO  Total__##!!??       43
6           Total__##!!??              F       41
7           Total__##!!??              M       26
8           Total__##!!??  Total__##!!??       67
```

Just copy above dataframe to clipboard and execute `df = pd.read_clipboard('\s\s+')` to load above dataframe.

I'm trying to transform it to following dataframe:

```py
                  stacked USUBJID
0      HISPANIC OR LATINO      NaN  <----- 
0                       F      16
1                       M       8
2           Total__##!!??      24
0  NOT HISPANIC OR LATINO      NaN  <-----
3                       F      25
4                       M      18
5           Total__##!!??      43
0           Total__##!!??      NaN  <-----
6                       F      41
7                       M      26
8           Total__##!!??      67
```

I want to stack `ETHNIC` and `SEX` columns together under the value of `ETHNIC` column for each unique values in `ETHNIC` column.

I was trying something like this, which works but is I don't think a robust solution.
I was trying to split it up to `n` (where n is the number of unique values in `EHTNIC` column) dataframes in a list with an empty row for each of the dataframe slices, then finally concatenating the list of the dataframe slices and doing the rest works.

```py
cols = ['ETHNIC',  'SEX']
results = []
for v in df[cols[0]].unique():
    results.append(pd.DataFrame([[None]*df.shape[1]], columns=df.columns))
    results.append(df[df[cols[0]].eq(v)])

results = pd.concat(results)
results[cols[0]] = results[cols[0]].bfill()
results['stacked'] = results.apply(lambda x: x['SEX'] if x['SEX'] else x['ETHNIC'], axis=1)
results = results.drop(columns=cols)[['stacked',  'USUBJID']]
```

Comment: kindly post the source code : ``df.to_dict('records')``. I am having difficulty in copyinng the shared data

Comment: @sammywemmy, Just copy the dataframe and try `df = pd.read_clipboard('\s\s+')` I tested it is working, and if it still doesn't work for you then let me know, I'll add it as `dict`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primarily for fun, here is another option based on [@Shubham Sharma's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68466667/16343464) that doesn't require defaultdict. Even the dependency on [numpy](https://numpy.org/) can be removed (see alternative at the end)

It only uses the [pandas.DataFrame](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html) constructor and [pandas.concat](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html).

```
import numpy as np
pd.concat([pd.DataFrame({'stacked': np.append(k, g['SEX']),
                         'USUBJID': np.append(np.NaN, g['USUBJID']),
                        })
           for k,g in df.groupby('ETHNIC')
          ])
```

output:

```
                  stacked  USUBJID
0      HISPANIC OR LATINO      NaN
1                       F     16.0
2                       M      8.0
3           Total__##!!??     24.0
0  NOT HISPANIC OR LATINO      NaN
1                       F     25.0
2                       M     18.0
3           Total__##!!??     43.0
0           Total__##!!??      NaN
1                       F     41.0
2                       M     26.0
3           Total__##!!??     67.0
```

alternative without numpy:

```
pd.concat([pd.DataFrame({'stacked': [k]+g['SEX'].to_list(),
                         'USUBJID': [None]+g['USUBJID'].to_list(),
                        })
           for k,g in df.groupby('ETHNIC')
          ])
```

Comment: I think this approach is cleaner than your previous answer.

Comment: I agree, I just didn't think of it at that time. It is also faster ;)

Answer (score 4):

Start by grouping on "ETHNIC" with [`pandas.DataFrame.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html).

Each group will contain a DataFrame and keep only the ['SEX', 'USUBJID'] columns, just with a different name for "SEX", which is changed using [`pandas.DataFrame.rename`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html).

The header is added taking the group name `d.name` and concatenating with the group DataFrame using [`pandas.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html)

Finally, the first level of the MultiIndex that results from the operation is dropped with [`pandas.DataFrame.reset_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html)

```py
(df.groupby('ETHNIC')
   .apply(lambda d: pd.concat([pd.DataFrame([{'stacked': d.name, 'USUBJID': np.NaN}]),
                               d[['SEX', 'USUBJID']].rename(columns={'SEX': 'stacked'})
                              ]))
   .reset_index(level=0, drop=True)
)
```

output:

```
                  stacked  USUBJID
0      HISPANIC OR LATINO      NaN
0                       F     16.0
1                       M      8.0
2           Total__##!!??     24.0
0  NOT HISPANIC OR LATINO      NaN
3                       F     25.0
4                       M     18.0
5           Total__##!!??     43.0
0           Total__##!!??      NaN
6                       F     41.0
7                       M     26.0
8           Total__##!!??     67.0
```

Comment: NB. depending on exactly which index you want you can play around with `reset_index`

Comment: I fixed a small error `d.name` instead of `name`

Comment: @ThePyGuy: it was ongoing, this is usually the part that takes most time ;)

Answer (score 2):

Let us try with `reshape`

```
from collections import defaultdict

def reshape():
    data = defaultdict(list)
    for k, g in df.groupby('ETHNIC'):
        data['stacked'] += [k, *g['SEX']]
        data['USUBJID'] += [np.nan, *g['USUBJID']]
    return data

pd.DataFrame(reshape())
```

---

```
                   stacked  USUBJID
0       HISPANIC OR LATINO      NaN
1                        F     16.0
2                        M      8.0
3            Total__##!!??     24.0
4   NOT HISPANIC OR LATINO      NaN
5                        F     25.0
6                        M     18.0
7            Total__##!!??     43.0
8            Total__##!!??      NaN
9                        F     41.0
10                       M     26.0
11           Total__##!!??     67.0
```

Comment: I guess `defaultdict` for the list of values in each group.

Comment: @ThePyGuy Yes, Exactly!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `groupby().apply()`

```
import io

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO("""                   ETHNIC            SEX  USUBJID
0      HISPANIC OR LATINO              F       16
1      HISPANIC OR LATINO              M        8
2      HISPANIC OR LATINO  Total__##!!??       24
3  NOT HISPANIC OR LATINO              F       25
4  NOT HISPANIC OR LATINO              M       18
5  NOT HISPANIC OR LATINO  Total__##!!??       43
6           Total__##!!??              F       41
7           Total__##!!??              M       26
8           Total__##!!??  Total__##!!??       67"""), sep="\s\s+", engine="python")

df.groupby("ETHNIC", as_index=False).apply(
    lambda d: pd.concat(
        [d.iloc[0,].to_frame().T.assign(USUBJID=np.nan),
         d.assign(ETHNIC=d.SEX),
        ]
    ).drop(columns="SEX")
).reset_index(drop=True)
```

|  | ETHNIC | USUBJID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | HISPANIC OR LATINO | nan |
| 1 | F | 16 |
| 2 | M | 8 |
| 3 | Total__##!!?? | 24 |
| 4 | NOT HISPANIC OR LATINO | nan |
| 5 | F | 25 |
| 6 | M | 18 |
| 7 | Total__##!!?? | 43 |
| 8 | Total__##!!?? | nan |
| 9 | F | 41 |
| 10 | M | 26 |
| 11 | Total__##!!?? | 67 |

Answer (score 1):

```
 # use `total` as a counter
(d.assign(total=lambda df: pd.Series(np.where(df.SEX.str.startswith("Total"), 
                                              df.index, np.nan)).bfill()
         )
.melt(['USUBJID', 'total'], ignore_index = False)
.sort_index()
.assign(temp = lambda df: df.variable.str.startswith("ETH").groupby(df.total).cumsum(), 
        USUBJID = lambda df: np.where(df.variable.str.startswith("ETH"), 
                                      np.nan, df.USUBJID))
 # keep only first row for `ETHNIC`
.query("variable == 'ETHNIC' and temp == 1 or variable=='SEX' and temp >= 1")
.drop(columns=['variable','total', 'temp'])
)


   USUBJID                   value
0      NaN      HISPANIC OR LATINO
0     16.0                       F
1      8.0                       M
2     24.0           Total__##!!??
3      NaN  NOT HISPANIC OR LATINO
3     25.0                       F
4     18.0                       M
5     43.0           Total__##!!??
6      NaN           Total__##!!??
6     41.0                       F
7     26.0                       M
8     67.0           Total__##!!??
```

Personally, the other answers are simpler and easier to grok