# Pandas stack multiple columns to a single column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have following DataFrame:

```py
                    ETHNIC                       RACE        AGE       TRT01A
0   NOT HISPANIC OR LATINO                      WHITE  31.824778  Treatment B
1   NOT HISPANIC OR LATINO                      WHITE  31.381246      Placebo
2       HISPANIC OR LATINO                      WHITE  45.522245  Treatment A
3       HISPANIC OR LATINO  BLACK OR AFRICAN AMERICAN  42.910335  Treatment B
4   NOT HISPANIC OR LATINO                      WHITE  31.381246      Placebo
5   NOT HISPANIC OR LATINO                      WHITE  38.045175  Treatment B
6       HISPANIC OR LATINO                      WHITE  39.337440      Placebo
7   NOT HISPANIC OR LATINO                      WHITE  47.121150      Placebo
8   NOT HISPANIC OR LATINO                      WHITE  38.203970  Treatment A
9   NOT HISPANIC OR LATINO  BLACK OR AFRICAN AMERICAN  22.926762      Placebo
10      HISPANIC OR LATINO                      WHITE  45.226557  Treatment B
11      HISPANIC OR LATINO                      WHITE  32.112252      Placebo
```

Just copy above dataframe to clipboard and run `df=pd.read_clipboard('\s\s+')` to get the dataframe into a variable.

```py
out = (df.groupby(['TRT01A','ETHNIC', 'RACE'])['AGE']
       .agg(mean=np.mean, 
            n='count', 
            deviation=np.std,
            Q1=lambda x: np.percentile(x, 0.25)
            )
       .T.unstack().unstack(0)
       )
```

I performed some aggregates in the above dataframe, and transposed, and successively unstacked them to get the following result:

```py
TRT01A                                                        Placebo  Treatment A  Treatment B
ETHNIC                 RACE                                                                    
HISPANIC OR LATINO     BLACK OR AFRICAN AMERICAN mean             NaN          NaN    42.910335
                                                 n                NaN          NaN     1.000000
                                                 deviation        NaN          NaN          NaN
                                                 Q1               NaN          NaN    42.910335
                       WHITE                     mean       35.724846    45.522245    45.226557
                                                 n           2.000000     1.000000     1.000000
                                                 deviation   5.108979          NaN          NaN
                                                 Q1         32.130315    45.522245    45.226557
NOT HISPANIC OR LATINO BLACK OR AFRICAN AMERICAN mean       22.926762          NaN          NaN
                                                 n           1.000000          NaN          NaN
                                                 deviation        NaN          NaN          NaN
                                                 Q1         22.926762          NaN          NaN
                       WHITE                     mean       36.627881    38.203970    34.934976
                                                 n           3.000000     1.000000     2.000000
                                                 deviation   9.087438          NaN     4.398485
                                                 Q1         31.381246    38.203970    31.840329
```

Now,  I want to unstack all the indices to get the following structure (i.e. inserting `NaN` rows for all the index columns from first to second last, alongwith `Level` column denoting the level of the index):

```py
                             Placebo  Treatment A  Treatment B  Level
HISPANIC OR LATINO               NaN          NaN          NaN      0 <---
BLACK OR AFRICAN AMERICAN        NaN          NaN          NaN      1 <---
mean                             NaN          NaN    42.910335      2
n                                NaN          NaN     1.000000      2
deviation                        NaN          NaN          NaN      2
Q1                               NaN          NaN    42.910335      2
WHITE                            NaN          NaN          NaN      1 <---
mean                       35.724846    45.522245    45.226557      2
n                           2.000000     1.000000     1.000000      2
deviation                   5.108979          NaN          NaN      2
Q1                         32.130315    45.522245    45.226557      2
NOT HISPANIC OR LATINO           NaN          NaN          NaN      0 <---
BLACK OR AFRICAN AMERICAN        NaN          NaN          NaN      1 <---
mean                       22.926762          NaN          NaN      2
n                           1.000000          NaN          NaN      2
deviation                        NaN          NaN          NaN      2
Q1                         22.926762          NaN          NaN      2
WHITE                            NaN          NaN          NaN      1 <---
mean                       36.627881    38.203970    34.934976      2
n                           3.000000     1.000000     2.000000      2
deviation                   9.087438          NaN     4.398485      2
Q1                         31.381246    38.203970    31.840329      2
```

This question is identical to the [previous question that I asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68466381/how-to-shift-and-stack-two-columns-of-pandas-dataframe-into-one-column), but the problem is, there can be from 1 to 4 indices columns after aggregating, (i.e. aggregate may be applied on from 1 to 5 columns), and it's being difficult to use the same previous solution in this scenario.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use custom function with [`DataFrame.append`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.append.html) first with custom `DataFrame` filled by default `NaN` values:

```
def f(x):
    names = pd.DataFrame(index=x.name, columns=x.columns).assign(Level=[0,1])
    #print (names)
    return names.append(x.reset_index(level=[0,1], drop=True).assign(Level=2))

out = out.groupby(level=[0,1], group_keys=False).apply(f)
```

And then remove duplicated `0` Levels:

```
out = out[~out.index.duplicated() | out['Level'].isin([1,2])]
```

---

```
print (out)
TRT01A                       Placebo  Treatment A  Treatment B  Level
HISPANIC OR LATINO               NaN          NaN          NaN      0
BLACK OR AFRICAN AMERICAN        NaN          NaN          NaN      1
mean                             NaN          NaN    42.910335      2
n                                NaN          NaN     1.000000      2
deviation                        NaN          NaN          NaN      2
Q1                               NaN          NaN    42.910335      2
WHITE                            NaN          NaN          NaN      1
mean                       35.724846    45.522245    45.226557      2
n                           2.000000     1.000000     1.000000      2
deviation                   5.108979          NaN          NaN      2
Q1                         32.130315    45.522245    45.226557      2
NOT HISPANIC OR LATINO           NaN          NaN          NaN      0
BLACK OR AFRICAN AMERICAN        NaN          NaN          NaN      1
mean                       22.926762          NaN          NaN      2
n                           1.000000          NaN          NaN      2
deviation                        NaN          NaN          NaN      2
Q1                         22.926762          NaN          NaN      2
WHITE                            NaN          NaN          NaN      1
mean                       36.627881    38.203970    34.934976      2
n                           3.000000     1.000000     2.000000      2
deviation                   9.087438          NaN     4.398485      2
Q1                         31.381246    38.203970    31.840329      2
```